# How to create a pandas Series from dict with non unique keys?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to create a pandas Series from dict that contains non-unique keys. But pandas keep discarding similar keys and loads only the last one.

```py
    my_dict1= {'Country':'US','Country':'UK','Country':'Japan','Country':'China',}
    pd.Series(my_dict1)
```

Output:

```
Country    China
dtype: object
```

Any turn arround possible that it inclues all the keys and values

Comment: you cant have a dict with same keys, is there a list of countries?

Comment: if you have a list of countries you can do `my_dict1={f'Country{e+1}':i for e,i in enumerate(countries)}` where `countries` is the name of list of countries. and then call `pd.Series()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dict needs unique keys. You need to do something as below, second option can be created by dict + zipping the list of countries with a range.

**Option 1**

```
my_dict1= {'Country1':'US','Country2':'UK','Country3':'Japan','Country4':'China',}
```

**Option 2**

```
country_list = ["US","UK"]
indexes = range(2)
country_dict = dict(zip(indexes,country_list))
```

**Output**

```
country_dict={'0':'US', '1':'UK',}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably change it to:

```py
pd.Series([v for k, v in mydict.items()])
```